# Is there a way to embed salesforce login screen into corporate website

Tags: partner-portal

Is there a way we can have partner portal login embeded in our corporate website. The idea is to allow the login form embeded in our corporate website and when the user fills in creds and submits goes to the partner portal directly. I want avoid the one extra click of going to login page and then filling in the credentials and then going to the portal if that is possible.

When i look at the source code of the login page of partner portal

```
<form base_target="_top" method="POST" action="/secur/login_portal.jsp" name="login">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="startURL">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="loginURL">
<input type="hidden" value="true" name="useSecure">
<input type="hidden" value="00Di0000000xxxx" name="orgId">
<input type="hidden" value="060i0000000xxxx" name="portalId">
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="loginType">
<input type="hidden" value="loginAction" name="action">
```

I tried using the same on form but on submission it would take me back to standard login page of partner portal.

Any thoughts on what can be the issue
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you can do this is to copy the form code from the salesforce's login page by looking at the view source.

```
<form  base_target="_top" action="https://na15.salesforce.com/secur/login_portal.jsp" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="/apex/defaultUrl" name="startURL">
    <input type="hidden" value="http://abc.com/abc" name="loginURL">
    <input type="hidden" value="true" name="useSecure">
    <input type="hidden" value="xxxi0000000xxx" name="orgId">
    <input type="hidden" value="xxxi0000000Uxxx" name="portalId">
    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="loginType">
    <input type="hidden" value="loginAction" name="action">
    <span>
    <i><img src="images/mail.png" alt="" /></i><input type="text" id="username" name="un" value="Enter your username" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your username';}">
    </span>
    <span>
    <i><img src="images/lock.png" alt="" /></i>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="pw">
                            </span>

    <h4><input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="remember_me"> Remember me</h4>

    <input type="submit" class="my-button"  value="Sign In">
    </form>
```

Make sure you have all the hidden variables and the name of the username and password field exactly same as its the source code of the login page of the portal

Answer (score 0):

Try using iframe on your current website that will point to login page.

Comment: I want to avoid iframes. Is there any other way

Comment: When the users login, you need to pass the Organisation id , partner portal Id, User Id of partner portal user, Corresponding Contact id and the user name.

 

Substitue the values in the url and re-direct - /servlet/servlet.su?oid=valoid&suportaluserid=userid&retURL=/conid&targetURL=/home/home.jsp&suportalid=custportalid

 

where valoid - corresponding organization

 

            Userid -customer portal user

 

            conid  - corresponding contact Id

 

            custportalid - Id of the corresponding customer portal where you need to login.

 

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you provide me with the link to this documentation. I am not sure where would i get the corresponding contactid. Is this code from within a VF page?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000096F2IAI